# Can't properly address an associated field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am accessing an external sql database. The rb file for that is

```
class CrmTable < ActiveRecord::Base

      self.abstract_class = true
      def self.table_name_prefix
        'dbo_'
      end
      establish_connection "crm_tables"
end

class Address < CrmTable
  self.table_name = "Address"
end

class Opportunity < CrmTable
  self.table_name = "Opportunity"
#  belongs_to :Person, foreign_key: :primarypersonid
  belongs_to :user
end


class CrmUser < CrmTable
  self.table_name = "Users"
  has_many :opportunities
end
```

I am trying to join and select with

```
@opportunities = @opportunities.joins(:users).where("users.name like ?", "%#{account_manager}%")
```

That gives me an error of

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError in Searches#show
Showing C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/product_development/app/views/searches/show.html.erb where line #18 raised:

Association named 'users' was not found on Opportunity; perhaps you misspelled it?
Rails.root: C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/product_development

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/searches/show.html.erb:18:in `_app_views_searches_show_html_erb__590262190_43507272'
```

Here is the log data:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Association named 'users' was not found on Opportunity; perhaps you misspelled it?):
    15: 
    16: <% if 5 == 5  then %>
    17: <hr>
    18: <%  @opportunities.each do |opportunity| %>
    19:     <hr>
    20: 
    21:     <h1>New item</h1>
  app/views/searches/show.html.erb:18:in `_app_views_searches_show_html_erb__590262190_43507272'
```

Notes
1 - I also have a table called users for adauth authentication. I'm not sure if that could be causing an issue. 
2 - The external database I am trying to access has a dbo schema prefix while the tables from the rails app are in a separate database with a pd_ schema prefix (I don't think that matters though)

Comment: could you please post your `database.yml`? and alsp that CrmTable should be a module, not a class, wich all the nested models are included into, not descendant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `belongs_to :user, class: 'CrmUser'`

Comment: That got me going in the right direction. I had to also add a foreign key to the belongs statement `  belongs_to :users, class_name: 'CrmUser', foreign_key:  :oppo_AssignedUserId`  as well as clean up my join statement to read ` @opportunities = @opportunities.joins(:users).where("users.User_LastName like ?", "%#{account_manager}%")`.  You did get me going in the right direction

Comment: good to hear. its nice AR has the hooks to be able to work with legacy systems. Good luck!